# Web analytics customer segmentation data modeling with Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I would like to use Cassandra for my website analytics which is geared especially towards customers segmentation.
What this analytics will do is gather Page View data for every customers/visitor which includes:

userName, country, city, gender, timeStamp, source, campaign, pageUrl, timeOnPage

This data will have to be sliced by all the dimensions for easy customer segmentation. For example:

SELECT * Users WHERE Country = USA AND pageUrl = "http://mystore.com/bestsettingproduct" AND timeStamp < DateTime.Now AND timeStamp > DateTime.Now - Days.30

OR

SELECT * Users WHERE Campaign = "Last Email Campaign" AND AND timeStamp < DateTime.Now AND timeStamp > DateTime.Now - Days.30

As I understand in Cassandra you can query only by key.
Given these sort of dynamic queries where one or more dimension can be included in the where clause, what would be a good data model?

I am thinking of having several tables with the following keys:

table 1 (userName, country, city, gender, timeStampWeek, timeStamp source, campaign, pageUrl, timeOnPage,

primary key(**(timeStampWeek, country)**, city, gender, timeStamp source, campaign, pageUrl, timeOnPage));

---

table 2 (userName, country, city, gender, timeStampWeek, timeStamp source, campaign, pageUrl, timeOnPage,

primary key(**(timeStampWeek, city)**, country, gender, timeStamp, source, campaign, pageUrl, timeOnPage));

---

table 3 (userName, country, city, gender, timeStampWeek, timeStamp, source, campaign, pageUrl, timeOnPage,

primary key(**(timeStampWeek, campaign)**, country, city, gender, timeStamp, source,  pageUrl, timeOnPage));

---

And so on for all combinations of the dimensions? But this seems wild? Could there be a smarter way to model around these queries?

Comment: which approach did you take?

Comment: We did not implement this kind of filters because the project changed direction. But my experience so far shows that this is the only approach with one important caveat. When you have a timeframe in your filter criteria and you want this implemented with Cassandra for example, your time frames need to be predefined. Otherwise, it is just impossible to do it with a nosql database, at least we did not find a way.